Converting 'on/off' JSON MQTT boolean payload to TRUE/FALSE in IF statement
I have the following message which is received as a MQTT payload
{ state: on, lightlevel: 1500 }
I am using an ESP32 and programming in C++
My ESP32 is subscribed to the topic and receives the payload fine.
I have an IF statement which should run if the state is 'on'
I have this code:
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

StaticJsonDocument <256> doc;
deserializeJson(doc,payload);

bool state = doc["state"];
int lightlevel = doc["lightlevel"];
 
  if (state == true){

      // stuff gets done here. 

  }

}

I was expecting the IF statement in the code above to run when 'on' is received... instead it does nothing.

How would StaticJsonDocument know to return on into true?

Have a look to the docs, and pay attention to the return type for the [] operator: https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsondocument/subscript/

the payload doesn't have a true/false in there, it has ON/OFF. find a way to have booleans represent ON/OFF and then make checks on the booleans. Like
response = {
   state : "ON"
}

check_true = "ON"
check_false = "OFF"

response_state = response["state"]

if response_state == check_true{
   //logic goes here
}else {
  //false logic goes here
}

i hope this helps

Thanks for your reply. I had tried that previously... I don't think the JSON data passed is actually being pulled out into the variables, as when I Serial.print bool and int, I get 00

@jack “ON” and “OFF” are neither booleans or integers, why do you think that assigning those values to a bool or int will get you a meaningful value? They’re strings. Assign the value to a string and work with that.
